# How can I keep track of which weights correspond to which layers and inputs in Keras/Tensorflow?

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

What is a good method of keeping track of what weights go where?  When I do `get_weights(model)`, I get a list of arrays, and I have to guess which ones correspond to which part of my model by their dimensionality.  How can I figure out which layers they're emanating from and connecting to, so that I can manipulate them programmatically?

I'm working in R, but answers in python can probably be translated.

Comment: Well (in Python) you can get the weights of each layer using `model.layers[layer_index].get_weights()` or `model.get_layer(layer_name_string).get_weights()`. And you can set their weights the same way using `set_weights()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [tensorflow debugger](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/debugger) in combination with naming your layers with names that make sense. After that you can execute a certain amount of iterations and check the values of the weights for a layer by using its name. Also you can check gradients for these layers.